# BOF at Spring One

Tags: java, spring

What is BOF ?

I can see lots of mentions of it but can not find a 'relevant' definition.

Bill

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birds_of_a_Feather_(computing)

A BoF session, an informal meet-up at conferences, where the attendees group together based on a shared interest and carry out discussions without any pre-planned agenda.